# Git diff showing Image file changed with Line CRLF with LF when its not a text file

Tags: git

When i do a git status i get below image file is changed. However its only image file and should not have any LF/CRLF in the file,

```
$ git status
# HEAD detached at origin/master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   public/css/chosen-sprite.png
```

When i type git diff to see the changes i got.

```
$ git diff public/css/chosen-sprite.png
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in public/css/chosen-sprite.png.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
diff --git a/public/css/chosen-sprite.png b/public/css/chosen-sprite.png
index c57da70..0476a8f 100644
Binary files a/public/css/chosen-sprite.png and b/public/css/chosen-sprite.png differ
```

So what i did was i tried to checkout the file to make sure its same as the remote origin file. So i did below

```
$git checkout public/css/chosen-sprite.png
```

But didn't make any changes above file or git status, still shows as it changed. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is in your `.gitattribuites` file?

Comment: to check what attributes are applied to a file : `git check-attr -a public/css/chosen-sprite.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, git treats all files as text, and converts line endings when you are using it on a machine with non-LF line endings, such as windows.  If you want it to treat a file as binary (and not convert the line endings) you must identify it as such in the .gitattributes file.  Something like

```
*.png binary
```

should do the trick.